# React Hooks and useEffect – best practices and server issues

Tags: react-native, server, react-hooks

I am using React Native with functional components. `componentDidMount()` etc. are not available in functional components, instead I use Hooks. But Hooks don't act like lifecycle methods. I am wondering what the best practices are.

Assumed that we have a function like this one:

```
const ABCScreen = () => {

  const [someHook, setSomeHook] = useState<any>()

  useEffect(() => {
    // some code inside this function which is called on every component update
  }, [])

  server.asyncCall().then(data => {
    setSomeHook(data)
  })

  return (<View>
    {someHook ? (<Text> `someHook` was assigned </Text>) : (<Text> `someHook` was not assigned, display some ActivityIndicator instead</Text>)}
  </View>)
}
```

Where to place server.asyncCall()? Inside or outside of useEffect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding here. The convention is that all the fetching data is going to be placed inside the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. React `useEffect` hook can replace this easily by placing an empty array of dependencies, which means you can place that call inside the `useEffect` you already have.

Unlike you mention in your code comment, this hook won't be triggered on each component update. It will be only be triggered once the component is being mounted. So, you should be able to do it as follows:

```
const ABCScreen = () => {

  const [someHook, setSomeHook] = useState<any>()

  useEffect(() => {
    server.asyncCall().then(setSomeHook)
  }, [])//only triggered when component is mounted.
```

In the future, you might want to check the [rules of the hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#:%7E:text=Only%20Call%20Hooks%20at%20the%20Top%20Level&text=Instead%2C%20always%20use%20Hooks%20at,multiple%20useState%20and%20useEffect%20calls.).

Comment: I thought that you place the declared hook states in the second param of the useEffect method and every time the hook state (or any var) is updated useEffect is called and if there is only a single empty array – useEffect is called every time the component was updated. But yes, there is at least a minor misunderstanding of React Hooks. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: The `useEffect` is going to be called on every update or render when you don't provide a second param at all, If you do provide an empty array it will be triggered only once.